# Matplotlib edgecolors coloring 0.0 valued data points

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I'm plotting a 3d bar plot for an array using matplotlib. I need to add an edgecolor to the bars. However, the edgecolor is coloring the 0.0 values data points in black. Is there a way to not color these data points? I'm trying to do edgecolors=none through a loop when values are 0.0. However this doesn't seem to help. Any help appreciated.

The script I use to plot,

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
lx= len(r[0])            
ly= len(r[:,0])
xpos = np.arange(0,lx,1)    
ypos = np.arange(0,ly,1)
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xpos+0.25, ypos+0.25)
xpos = xpos.flatten()   
ypos = ypos.flatten()
zpos = np.zeros(lx*ly)

cs = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y', 'c'] * ly
edgecolor_store = []

dx = 0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dy = 0 * np.ones_like(zpos)
#dz = zpos
dz = r.flatten()
for value in dz: 
    if value == 0.0:
        edgecolor_store.append('none')
    if value > 0.0:
        edgecolor_store.append('black')

 
mask_dz = dz == 0 # SO:60111736, 3d case
#print(dz)
ax.bar3d(xpos,ypos,zpos, dx, dy,dz,color=cs,zsort='average',alpha=0.5,edgecolors=edgecolor_store)
```

Sample data I use,

```
[  0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ],[  0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ],[  0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ],[  0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ],[  0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ],[  0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ],[  0. ,   0. ,  20.7,   0. ,   0. ],[  0.6,   0. ,   0.1,   0. ,   0.2],[  0. ,  24.8,   0. ,  46.7,   0. ],[  0. ,   0. ,  99.7,  17.1,  99.3],[  0. ,  12.8,  98.6,   0. ,   6.7],[  0.2,   0. ,   0. ,  12.6,   0. ]
```

The output plot I get is,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel that you've already tried the correct solution: not plot the unwanted bars.

You need a mask. Btw, never ever compare floats with `==`.

```py
mask = ~np.isclose(dz, 0.0)
```

Then, plot data filtered by this mask

```
ax.bar3d(xpos[mask],ypos[mask],zpos[mask], dx[mask], dy[mask],dz[mask],color=cs[:mask.sum()],zsort='average',alpha=0.5,edgecolors='black')
```

Note that you no longer need edgecolor. And that my way of computing `cs` (starting from your too long `cs`, and truncating it to the exact needed size) is not optimal.

[image]

Also note that the 4 remaining black lines are not 0, but very small (0.1, 0.2, 0.2 and 0.6) values.

Comment: Beautiful ! thank you !